# struct errors when adding <windows.h>

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
I have created two structs called PERSON and DATE
```

i want to add music at a certain line, i understand that in order to do this
 i need to have windows.h . The only problem is, when i add this header file, i get a bunch of C2223 errors in two of my DATE struct functions. They all say

```
"left of '->month' must point to struct/union   structs"
```

here are the functions where the errors are

```
oid getDate(DATE *d)
{
    printf("\nEnter the year: ");
    scanf("%i", &d->year); //the errors are with lines like these
    while (d->year > 2018 || d->year < 1890)
    {
        printf("Thats not a valid option, try again\n");
        printf("\nEnter the year: ");
        scanf("%i", &d->year);
    }

    printf("\nEnter the month: ");
    scanf("%i", &d->month); //pass by reference d->value or *d.value
    while (d->month > 12 || d->month <= 0)
    {
        printf("Thats not a valid option, try again\n");
        printf("\nEnter the month: ");
        scanf("%i", &d->month);
    }

    printf("\nEnter the day: ");
    scanf("%i", &d->day);
    while (d->day > 31 || d->day <= 0)
    {
        printf("Thats not a valid option, try again\n");
        printf("\nEnter the day: ");
        scanf("%i", &d->day);
    }

    while ((d->month == 2) && ((d->year % 4) == 0))
    {
        if (d->day > 28)
        {
            printf("Thats not a valid date for a leap year, try again\n");
            printf("\nEnter the day: ");
            scanf("%i", &d->day);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

}
void displayDate(DATE *d) {
    printf("%02i/%02i/%004i", d->month, d->day, d->year); // %2i means a width of 2. The 0 is just a place holder // for a single digit date printf("\n");
}
```

I am not familiar with how windows.h works, do i need to remove the *?

Comment: can someone answer this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FIXED THE PROBLEM BY MYSELF since no one else seemed to know.

What happens is windows.h already has a DATE struct included in it so I had to rename my DATE struct to be something like DNTE and it worked just fine.

And for those who wanna know how to add music just add

```
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Winmm.lib")
```

in addition to the `<stdio.h>` and `<stdlib.h>`

and you must first open it then play it, like a file. So

```
mciSendString("open \"filename.mp3\" type mpegvideo alias mp3", NULL, 0, NULL); //open
mciSendString("play mp3", NULL, 0, NULL); //play
```

Comment: You can accept it in a couple of days.  I only just looked at the question, and I'd've only been able to ask questions about "what does `<windows.h>` define that collides with your variable and type names".  I'm not clear how you got your code to compile with the `<windows.h>` header and with name clashes on the `DATE` type.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well what i did i just renamed the DATE struct (which i defined manually prior to adding windows.h) to DNTE or any other name. So the name clashes go away